# Is that possible test flutter apps with WebdriverIO?

Tags: webdriver-io

Can I test flutter app (for example in apk) using WebdriverIO?

I saw there is a flutter driver for Appium. Is it supported with WebriverIO as well? How is it handled?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You have to use **[Appium Automation](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-flutter-apps-with-appium)** to interact with your Flutter mobile app.

1. Setup your own WebdriverIO Appium project, or start from a featured [boilerplate](https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate), as such.
2. Integrate the [appium-flutter-driver](https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver) into your project and start using it inside your test cases.

---

LE: Alternatively, you can try SauceLab's Appium-Flutter-Driver implementation using WebdriverIO. See it **[here](https://github.com/saucelabs-training/demo-js/tree/main/webdriverio/appium-app/examples/appium-flutter)**.

You can find multiple examples online for configurations. A simple Google search even gives you a full [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv74YaISJSg&ab_channel=ConfEngine) on how to setup everything.